# Perl: How to use map to project an array of pairs to an array of first elements

Tags: arrays, perl, list

I have this simple code:

```
 perl -e '@A=([1,2],[3,4]); @B=map {$_[0]} @A; print @B'
```

My goal is to do the transformation:

```
([1,2],[3,4]) -> (1,3)
```

The code gives no output. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dereference the references:

```
perl -e '@A = ([1, 2], [3, 4]); @B = map { $_->[0] } @A; print @B'
                                             ^^
```

Check

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: and don't forget to enable warnings

Comment: I started using Perl just a few days ago (Btw, blown away by its awesomeness!!), so not familiar with warnings.
Some use cases would be great!

Comment: @vervenumen: Just add `-w` to your original code and see what it tells you.

Comment: @vervenumen Definitely read the [docs that come with Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org) (I originally learned Perl from reading the docs and from the syntax error messages).